# Attempting to Convert from SS2K to SS2K8 -- Having problem changing Compatibility

Tags: sql-server-2008, compatibility

I am running a prototype of our production environment in Development and have been asked to scout out the problems we would have doing a conversion from SS2K to SS2K8.

I ran the SS "Best Practices" wizard and the "Upgrade Advisor". Then I went to change the compatibility from 2000 to 2008. In the Object Explorer, I selected the database, right-clicked and selected Properties, then selected Options. In the Compatibility List Box, ***only*** SS2k and SS7 were listed!

Does anyone have an idea how I would get SS2K8 to be one of the options?

Thanks ahead of time for any help you can offer!

-- Tom

Comment: This is in a server running 2008?

Answer (score 0):

You can set compatibility mode backwards but not forwards.  For example, you can set compatibility mode on SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2000 but not SQL Server 2000 to 2005.

It would be difficult for Microsoft's programmers to setup a compatibility mode for something that does not yet exist.